# Are settings in System > Preferences > Startup Applications the same as settings in some system or personal configuration file?

Tags: startup, autostart

We can set up what programs to start automatically when starting up the OS, by adding settings in System > Preferences > Startup Applications

Is this method the same as adding settings in some system or personal configuration file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, ...)?

When do the programs set to auto start at startup actually start? (Those files I mentioned differ in the timing.)

Thanks.